# Query on SQL Server Express is taking too long to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables Channel and ChannelData. Channel Table has 40 records, every minute a record will be inserted in to ChannelData table for each Channel in the Channel Table. Now ChannelData table has more than 15 million records in it. I wrote a query as following to get the latest logged values for the 40 Channels in ChannelData Table.

```
select
    max(chnldata.Id) as ChannelDataId,
    chnl.id as ChannelId,
    chnl.ChannelName as ChannelName,
    chnldata.ChannelValue as channelValue,
    chnl.ChannelMonitoringUnits as ChannelUnits, 
    chnldata.ChannelDataLogTime as channelDataLogTime,
    chnl.StationId,
    chnldata.Active
from
    ChannelData as chnldata                        
    inner join Channel as chnl on chnl.Id = chnldata.ChannelId 
where
    chnl.Active = 1
    and
    chnldata.ChannelDataLogTime in 
        (SELECT
            MAX(chnldata1.ChannelDataLogTime)
         FROM
            ChannelData as chnldata1
         where 
            chnldata1.ChannelId = chnl.Id)                        
group by
    chnldata.Id,
    chnl.id,
    ChannelName,
    ChannelValue,
    chnl.ChannelMonitoringUnits,
    ChannelDataLogTime,
    chnl.StationId,
    chnldata.Active
```

When I am executing this query on SQLServer 2008 Express Edition it is taking 29 minutes to get the results, but when i tried to run the same query on SQLServer 2008 Standard Edition it took less than 1 min on a database with ChannelData table of 15 million records. Is there any other way to write this query, so that I could get the results in less than a minute in SQL Server 2008 Express.

Answer (score 0):

Your other server probably has more indexes defined. Indexes aren't included in `Generate Scripts` by default for some reason, so you might want to look at that.

Use the SQL Server Profiler tool (you'll have this with your Standard SKU installer, but you can use it against SQL Server Express). Also look at the `Actual Execution Plan` (*not* the `Estimated Execution Plan`) command, look for `Table Scan` or `Index Scan` - that will reveal inefficiencies that can be fixed with an appropriate index.

See here http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/30/sql-server-index-seek-vs-index-scan-table-scan/